# divide the values from pandas df column by number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divide

I need to divide every value of a column by 25. Below is my code:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].div(25)
```

I've gotten an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`
Then I tried to convert Object datatype to int with the following code:

```
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

The error message: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'`

Comment: Try `df["Amount"].astype(float).div(25)`

Comment: [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) is the flexible way to convert a column to a numeric dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) function, in case you want to specify it's a float column you could try the downcast parameter, although it will most likely be OK if you don't add it.

```py
df["Amount"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Amount"], downcast='float')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"]/25
print(df)
```